# MS Azure Blob/CDN "The account being accessed does not support http." forward http to https

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I recently moved my static website to Azure blob with a CDN using a CDN managed certificate.  I thought everything was good until I went out to my site and discoverd when I went to www.example.com I received the following message:

```
The account being accessed does not support http.
HttpStatusCode: 400
ErrorCode: AccountRequiresHttps
RequestId : 64466600-xxxx
TimeStamp : 2020-04-02T14:18:52.1757112Z
```

However if I go to https://www.example.com it comes up ok.

Is there a way to forward http traffic to https in azure blob/CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow this guide:

https://medium.com/azure-architects/configuring-azure-cdn-http-https-redirection-2a9e4aab0a77

1. From the Azure Portal Select the CDN profile
2. Click on Manage to open the configuration page
3. From the HTTP Large menu, select Rules Engine
4. Update the Name / Description i.e. HTTP to HTPS redirect
5. Change the Always dropdown menu to Request Scheme
6. Click the Features+ button and select URL Redirect
7. Within the pattern text field enter (.*)
8. In the Destination text field enter https://%{host}/$1
9. Click Add

Comment: thanks!  This looks like it was from an older version but it got me to where I needed to be.  I'll update your response with the steps I took and accept it as the correct solution.

Comment: To be noted that this is not supported for Standard Akamai CDN profile. I created a feedback idea in order to make it possible.